# Providing c++ iterators for a legacy C linked-list interface

Tags: c++, iterator, wrapper

I have a Visual Studo 2008 C++ application where I am trying to add iterator support to a legacy C-API's linked-list structure.  The C interface looks like this:

```
typedef struct _LINKED_LIST_INFO {
    struct _LINKED_LIST_INFO* Next;
    const char* name;
    // more elements. some are fixed-size; others are pointers to other structures.
} LINKED_LIST_INFO;

DWORD GetLinkedList( LINKED_LIST_INFO* pInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen );
```

I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
int _tmain( int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[] )
{
    MyLinkedList elements;
    for( MyLinkedList::const_iterator it = elements.begin();
         it != elements.end();
         ++it )
    {
        printf( "Name: %s\r\n", it->Name().c_str() );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, I've created these 3 classes. But, my `MyInfoIterator` class has a problem with the `operator->()`. I can't return a temporary pointer to `MyInfo`, so I get the error: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'MyInfo' to 'const MyInfo *'`

What is a good solution to this problem?

```
/// wrap the legacy C structure and provide C++ accessors
class MyInfo
{
public:

    MyInfo( const LINKED_LIST_INFO& info ) : elem_( info ) { };

    std::string Name() const { return elem_.name; };

private:
    /// one element of the linked list
    const LINKED_LIST_INFO& elem_;
}; // class MyInfo

namespace detail {

/// buffer to hold the legacy C linked-list
typedef std::vector< BYTE > MyBuffer;

/// iterator support for the legacy C linked-list
class MyInfoIterator 
    : public std::iterator< std::input_iterator_tag, MyInfo > 
{
public:
    explicit MyInfoIterator( MyBuffer& list ) : data_( list )
    {
        elem_ = reinterpret_cast< LINKED_LIST_INFO* >( &data_.front() );
    };

    MyInfoIterator() : elem_( NULL ) { };

    MyInfoIterator& operator++() 
    {
        elem_ = elem_->Next;
        return *this;
    };

    value_type operator*() { return *elem_; };

    //  error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'MyInfo' to 'const MyInfo *'
    const value_type* operator->() { return elem_; };

    friend bool operator==( const MyInfoIterator& i, 
                            const MyInfoIterator& j ) 
    { 
        return i.elem_ == j.elem_;
    };

private:

    /// linked-list of elements
    MyBuffer data_;

    /// current position within the element list
    LINKED_LIST_INFO* elem_;

}; // class MyInfoIterator

bool operator!=( const MyInfoIterator& i, const MyInfoIterator& j ) 
{ 
    return !operator==( i, j );
}

}; // namespace detail

/// provide iterator access for the legacy C linked-list API
class MyLinkedList
{
public:
    typedef detail::MyInfoIterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const 
    { 
        ULONG size = sizeof( LINKED_LIST_INFO );
        detail::MyBuffer buffer( size );

        DWORD ec = ::GetLinkedList( 
            reinterpret_cast< LINKED_LIST_INFO* >( &buffer.front() ), &size );
        if( ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW == ec )
        {
            buffer.resize( size );
            ec = ::GetLinkedList( 
                reinterpret_cast< LINKED_LIST_INFO* >( &buffer.front() ), &size );
        }

        if( ERROR_SUCCESS != ec )
            Win32Exception::Throw( ec );

        return const_iterator( buffer ); 
    };

    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(); };

}; // class MyInfo
```

Thanks,
PaulH

**Edit:**

I cannot change the legacy API or it's associated structure.

**Edit2:**

I think I have a working solution that preserves my intent of hiding the underlying linked-list implementation and maintains the separation of responsibilities for each class by returning the address of a `static MyInfo`.

```
class MyInfo
{
   // ...
protected:
    MyInfo() : info_( NULL ) { };
    void Set( const LINKED_LIST_INFO* info ) { info_ = info; };
private:
    friend MyInfoIterator;
    const LINKED_LIST_INFO* info_;
};

const value_type& MyInfoIterator::operator*() const 
{ 
    static MyInfo info;
    info.Set( elem_ );
    return info;
};

const value_type* MyInfoIterator::operator->() const
{ 
    static MyInfo info;
    info.Set( elem_ );
    return &info; 
};
```

Comment: `return &elem_;` ... good luck and keep an ice pick handy just in case.

Comment: ignore the morbid sense of humor :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is horrible (you should not do this) :

```
class MyInfo {
   char* name() const {
      return ((_LINKED_LIST_INFO*)this)->name;
   }
};

class MyInfoIterator 
: public std::iterator< std::input_iterator_tag, MyInfo>
{
   _LINKED_LIST_INFO* p;
public:
    MyInfoIterator(LINKED_LIST_INFO* pointer) : p(pointer) {}

    [Same as you did]

    reference operator*() const { return *(MyInfo*)p; }
};
```

The clean way is probably :

```
class MyInfo {
public:

  [...]

  private:
    const LINKED_LIST_INFO* elem_;
}

class MyInfoIterator 
: public std::iterator< std::input_iterator_tag, MyInfo>
{
   mutable MyInfo p;
public:
    MyInfoIterator(LINKED_LIST_INFO* pointer) : p(pointer) {}

    [...]

    reference& operator*() const { return p; }
    pointer_type operator->() const { return &p; }
};
```

This is how some Boost iterator are implemented (I mean the clean way, not the first one), see [1] for example.

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html

Comment: I agree that looks horrible, but I don't understand: if it's horrible why are you putting it in your answer?

Comment: Your operator* returns a value_type instead of a reference. It should return a reference instead. This is an horrible workaround (is it legal ?). The clean way is probably to implement the iterator as having a MyInfo (its member should not be an reference however).

Comment: I think my horrible solution is cleaner :) You will run into problems if you are using more than one iterator of this type at the same type (think nested loops, think multiple thread).

Comment: I am going to use your mutable solution, I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple :

```
class MyInfoIterator 
    : public std::iterator< std::input_iterator_tag, _LINKED_LIST_INFO >
{
   _LINKED_LIST_INFO* p;
public;
    MyInfoIterator(_LINKED_LIST_INFO* pointer) : p(pointer) {}

    [Same as you did]

    value_type& operator*() { return *p; }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to expose the Next pointer in the linked list. So, I am returning an accessor class (`MyInfo`) that hides the underlying LL implementation.

Comment: +1: This illustrates the value type issue I mentioned and is valid if you don't need the helper class for access, if you do substitute `MyInfo` instead of `LINKED_LIST_INFO` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `value_type` is wrong ... if you inherit STL iterator as an interface the value type needs to be of the type you contain.  In your case you say that you contain elements of `MyInfo` but you are attempting to return a `LINKED_LIST_INFO*`

Either return a `MyInfo` or declare your iterator container to have a `value_type` of `LINKED_LIST_INFO`.

Probably want the first option as you may need the helper class for accessor methods to be able to properly manipulate the members of the struct.

Edit:

Naturally you should realize that simply having a `std::vector<LINKED_LIST_INFO>` or `std::vector<MyInfo>` gives you all the functionality you need with none of the implementation and maintenance issues.

Edit #2:

Actually you can't have a `std::vector<MyInfo>` because it's not default constructible so once you resolve your current error you will get another one based on `typedef std::vector< MyInfo > MyBuffer;` which will fail to resolve in template construction until you provide a default constructor for `MyInfo`

Edit #3:

Your `value_type operator*() { return *elem_; }` is rather improperly formed.  You should not return a copy of the internal object after this binary operation.  You should return a reference.  In your case you're treating this as a deref rather than a multiplication operation which is fine but a copy-by-value return is still wrong.

Comment: I do not want to expose the Next pointer in the linked list. So, I am returning an accessor class (`MyInfo`) that hides the underlying LL implementation.

Comment: I can use neither `std::vector<MyInfo>` nor `std::vector<LINKED_LIST_INFO>`. The underlying linked list structure is variably sized (and not in multiples of `sizeof LINKED_LIST_INFO`), so the vector must be a BYTE array. That's what I was trying to communicate with the comment line in the `LINKED_LIST_INFO` structure and by having the `const char* name` parameter in there.

Comment: const char* is always same size ... it's a pointer to constant char data. Even in the case of char* and dynamic allocation of internal members the pointer size remains the size of a pointer. It is however dangerously precarious design in modern C++ you should be wary of ever _seeing_ `delete` or `delete[]` in well designed OOP code. Prefer smart pointers. Still the point about pointers remains the same. `sizeof(LINKED_LIST_INFO)` is probably not changing ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Neither `delete` nor `delete[]` is used here. `sizeof LINKED_LIST_INFO` stays the same, but I cannot use a `vector<LINKED_LIST_INFO>` because `LINKED_LIST_INFO` isn't an array of types it is a linked list. This: `LINKED_LIST_INFO* a=/*...*/; ++a;` would be wrong.

Comment: RE: Edit3 - If I change the `operator*()` to return a reference to `value_type`, then I'm going to run in to the same trouble I have with `operator->()` where I'm returning the address of a temporary variable.

Comment: That was a case of too much info sorry to be confusing.  So what you are saying is that `LINKED_LIST_INFO` is using nodes and the memory is not allocated contiguously.  Fair enough use `std::vector<MyInfo>` and design the helper class `MyInfo` to deal with data access and hopping from node to node.

Comment: @AJG85 - That's a possibility. I would prefer to keep the responsibility of the `MyInfo` class to data access, but if nothing else works out I will use the method you're suggesting.

Comment: It's just simpler to have a container class which also provides the operator overloads you need for iterating rather than having a container class and a manipulating class that uses the container class and then an interface which uses that, etc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just returning the address of `elem_` should do it.

`const value_type* operator->() { return &elem_; };`

Are you sure it wouldn't be less work to change your legacy list to a `std::list` or `std::vector` as appropriate though?

Comment: That change gives me a `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'LINKED_LIST_INFO **' to 'const MyInfo *'` error. I cannot change the legacy API or its associated structure.

Comment: If you're suggesting I do this: `const value_type* operator->() { return &AdapterInfo( elem_ ); };` Then, I'm returning the address of a non-lvalue.